# can not select Id of a persian value from the microsoft sql server in android

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have MSSQL DB,wich is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation and filled out with some persian values,
the type of the field stored in DB is String(nvarchar(50), null)
I want to get the ID of this String,that is Integer.
so i open my Connection and write this in my code :

```
                ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                statement2 = connectionHelper.getConnection().createStatement();
                setType();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement2.executeQuery("select Id from tblProductCategory where Name='" + getType() + "'");
```

But i couldnt.
getType() return a string in persion from my GridView.

After hours, i insert Latin String in my tblProductCategory and select its ID, and it worked correctly. My problem is with Persian Language.
i searched and find that mssql server doesnt have utf-8, but nvarchar support this.
any Idea?

Comment: just a tip: use PreparedStatement instead of '"+getType()+"'

Comment: just a tip: do not use jdbc on android at all...

Comment: @StefanBeike 
getType is my own method which returns a value of my ListView Adapter.
Here is setType:

    public void setType()
    {
type=typeAdapter.getItem(dairyType.getCheckedItemPosition()).toStrin);
    }
And getType
    public static String getType() {
        return type;
    }
What do mean use preparedStatement?

Comment: @Selvin 
I use jtds to connect sql server, so how can i connect to my DB to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I have to inset N before my String.It means my Query change to :

```
            ResultSet resultSet = statement2.executeQuery("select Id from tblProductCategory where Name=N'" + getType() + "'");
```